# Not able to send Composer(airflow job) to dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-composer, dataproc

Im trying to submit an airflow job in composer (gcp) to dataproc. When i do this i get the following error

ask failed with exception Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 1955, in execute job_object = self.hook.submit_job( File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 468, in inner_wrapper return func(self, *args, **kwargs) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 789, in submit_job return client.submit_job( File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1/services/job_controller/client.py", line 494, in submit_job request = jobs.SubmitJobRequest(request) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 516, in **init** pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 211, in to_proto pb_value = rule.to_proto(value) File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 36, in to_proto return self._descriptor(**value) ValueError: Protocol message JobReference has no "projectId" field.

Odd thing is the project id is there and valid ?

```
submit_dataproc_task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
    task_id='submit_spark_job_to_dataproc',
    project_id='my-project',
    region='my-region',  # Replace with your actual Dataproc region
    job={
        'reference': {'projectId': my-project-id},
        'placement': {'clusterName': my-cluster},
        'sparkJob': {
            'mainClass': '',
            'jarFileUris': ['{{ task_instance.xcom_pull("download_jar_task") }}'],
            'args': [],
            'properties': {
                'spark.corebanking.input.dir': 'file:///home/sample.avro'
            }
        }
    },
    dag=dag,
)
```

I've also trying some other dic/list config but keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is referencing this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dataproc.v1#jobreference). that jobreference doesnt have a "projectid" field but instead "project_id". can you try replacing projectid in `'reference': {'projectId': my-project-id}` to `project_id`